# how to synchronize multiple d3 charts when zoomed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, d3.js, charts

```
 function chart (data, selector) { 
        // generate chart with zoom feature. it scales the X domain and update the chart accordingly. 
    } 
chart(dataset1, "#chart1")
chart(dataset2, "#chart2")
chart(datasetn, "#chartn")
```

the code above is a chart generator function which I give it different datasets to make me charts. in all charts, the dataset has the same X values but different Y values.

problem:

lets say we have 3 charts, all the X axis ranges are between 0-100. In the first chart, I drag mouse and create a zoombox between 30-60 and the first chart updates, now it is scaled between 30-60. But the second and third chart are intact. I need them to be updated as well between 30-60.

similarly if I do the same for second chart, I need the first and third one get updated.

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgrnjynL/3/) to illustration

Comment: Create a demo using jsfiddle, explain what should happen when you do X/Y/Z, and what have you tried so far...

Comment: That is too much code :( let me more clarify my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's too much code. If you want help you should let other people basic structure to work with...

Comment: @Dekel I added the fiddle. Would you mind to check. thanks,

Comment: Now it's something we can work with :) not sure i'll be able to provide a solution atm but i'll check it tomorrow if no one will answer before...

Comment: @Dekel let me know if you need more info. thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I made not so big modification to make this works. 
First of all we remember globally the information about single chart in var `charts` array. This is done during creation of charts

```
charts.push(lineChart(data1,"#chart1"));
charts.push(lineChart(data2,"#chart2"));
charts.push(lineChart(data3,"#chart3"));
```

Next we can use this array in function `zoomdrag` and `update`.
This work maybe not perfect (reset of chart is missing) but show how to handle it and get the same zoom in all charts. 
Here is  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz1fdbxd/)

Comment: Thanks, It was a great idea! for refreshing since I am using angular, should I use watcher inside the lineChart() func and refresh the chart in there or you have a better idea?

Comment: Yeah, sure you can do this. One thing which you have to handle is to synchronize changes and avoid end loop of updates.

Comment: I noticed that tooltip is not working on safari. I am using foreignObject to make that. do you know why is that? couldnot resolve it yet.